# How to visualize functions of an R package?

Tags: r, function, package

I was wondering if it was possible to visualize the body of a function of a package in R. I'll be more specific with an example: I am trying to visualize the body of the function `fpkmSCVPlot` of cummeRbund Bioconductor package. I tried just to type `fpkmSCVPlot` but the output is not the actual function:

> standardGeneric for "fpkmSCVPlot" defined from package "cummeRbund"
> function (object, FPKMLowerBound = 1, ...)
> standardGeneric("fpkmSCVPlot") <bytecode: 0x7f79b3fca100>
> <environment: 0x7f79b3fe9b50> Methods may be defined for arguments:
> object, FPKMLowerBound Use  showMethods(fpkmSCVPlot)  for currently
> available ones.

I have also looked up the web, but I have not found any specific answer.

Thank you in advance,

Giuseppe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function

Comment: @Roland I think it would involve `BiocManager::install("cummeRbund", destdir = ".", force = TRUE)`, then unzip. But when I search the entire package directory for `fpkmSCVPlot` I see 12 matches in 7 files, but I can't see anywhere where it's actually defined/aliased. (note: I think the steps under 'Compiled code in a package' section of the link you provide are the right instructions to follow, but I am not sure of that)